# Comparing mean difference of categorical variables

Tags: categorical-data, stata, ordinal-data, mean

I want to check if attrition is a problem. So I want to check if the mean of people who dropped out from a survey is significantly different from the mean of those people who took part. However, the variable I want to check this for is a categorical variable (maternal education, split up in three categories: no education, primary education, secondary education and above).

If I compare the mean of this categorical variable of the people who took part and those who didn't, can I still use a t-test (e.g. Welch test) or do I have to use another test?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Welcome to CV! It sounds like your variable is ordinal, rather than categorical. If that's correct, consider editing your question and adding related tags.

Comment: Is this not what MANOVA is about?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a cumulative-link regression that predicts the education level with one binary *study status* factor (dropped out/stayed in); see `ordinal` package in `R`.

If your stats package doesn't have an ordinal regression function like this, you could use a series of logistic regressions, e.g.,

- no education (0) vs primary education (1) predicted by study status
- primary education (0) vs secondary + education (1) predicted by study status

It's not appropriate to use a *t*-test (or non-parametric *t*-test like wilcoxon) with the ordinal data you have because the difference between the levels in your dependent variable is not reflected in the value-assignment that is being discussed in this post.

Answer (score 0):

To be more specific then SeanEaster. You can always give arbitrary numerical values to each category and then calculate the mean. ie. 0= no education, 1=primary education, 2=secondary education and then calculate a mean.

The problem with this is that the data is ordinal and that means that the numerical value you get from this mean dont mean anything. You cant say that primary education is twice as good as no education, or a tenth as good as secondary education.

So what you can do is use Kruskal-Wallis Test and test if one category have a different median then the other(s).

Comment: Great, thank you Druleful for the explanation! I did a bit of a research and found that I could also use the Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney test. In stata this would be the following command: ranksum educmother, by (attrition). So I test if the education of the mother differs across the different categories of attrition (left survey vs. took part). Apparently this test is similar to a t-test, just for categorical variables.  Do you think that's also ok?

Comment: Just remamber that the hypothesis your testing with Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney is if the different groups comes from the same distribution or not. Further I think that you can only compare two groups with that test.

Comment: But the Kruskal-Wallis Test tests also tests for the equality of the median age distribution. What's the difference here? And is there also a test with mean instead of median or does mean not make sence with categories? Comparing only 2 groups is no problem since I want to compare only the "attrition" group with the "participating" group.